# Not getting 2.2 kV output on a microwave transformer

Tags: transformer, ac

I'm setting up a microwave transformer for the purpose of high-voltage woodburning

I'm trying to validate the output voltage that I'm getting before proceeding with the project. I'm measuring the output voltage with a multimeter and three 1 MΩ resistors in series. I'm measuring the voltage across one resistor since I'm expecting up to around 700 V, which is 300 V shy of the 1000 V limit of my multimeter.

Measuring the resistance of the two white wires, and the red wire, the two white wires have near 0 Ω resistances (assumed that's the secondary winding), and the resistance from the white wires to the red wire is around 1.5 MΩ.

When measuring the voltage across each possible wire combination, I'm only getting a maximum output voltage of 4.2 V (1.4 V per resistor, so 4.2 V in total). I don't understand why I'm not getting 700 V. I wonder if either my transformer is damaged, or if my primary and secondary windings are incorrect.

For reference, my input voltage is 120 VAC at 60 Hz.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well, if you had primary and secondary the wrong way round you would only register a few volts but, unless you are planning to exercise your right to prove Darwin's theorem on the survival of the fittest (negatively) I'd say you stop this right now and get some local expert help.

Comment: Just looking at those bare conductors makes me feel nervous.

Comment: (a) seriuosly, don't run this at full voltage, unless you're an experienced HV designer and have HV precautions.
(b) start with 12 VAC in not 120VAC. Use a step down transfprmer or variac to check things.

Comment: (c) Looks like your using convention low-power low voltage resistors. I doubt they will withstand 700V.  I'd limit any resistor's voltage to approx 100V max. So use more in series. Or, special high-voltage resistors are sold if that's what you really need.

Comment: (d) use HV insulating tubing ("spaghetti") over all the HV wires & connections. Choose one that's rated for at least 2-times your actual highest voltage.  Potting the final build, in high-quality encapsulant (e.g. epoxy), is another option.

Comment: (e) ensure that in all the HV wiring, there are no sharp connections, stray strands of wire, unsmooth solder joints, etc. Use "ball soldering" method  HV fields concentrate at sharp points, can cause corona discharge, which can damage the insulation.

Comment: (f) (may not apply here but just in case) make sure any capacitors have "bleeder" resistors across them. Then after you switch it from On to Off, you wait enough time for the caps to get discharged to very low, safe voltage.

Comment: (g) A large clear plastic (plexiglass) shield between you & the work is very good idea.  And plenty of space behind the work. So if something blows up, the flying pieces will not hit you.  (At least, wear safety glasses.  High-voltage gloves are also available, for professionals who regularly work on this stuff.)

Comment: (h) Do not work on it live, even if to probe it, or clip a wire. Always shut it off between every change, no matter what it is. Working on HV circuits is slow work, & not for the impatient.

Comment: Why use kilovolts for wood burning?  The wood burning tools that I'm familiar with, use direct line voltage 120VAC and heat the wood, (and look like specialized soldering irons.)

Comment: @RichS My goal was to make a lichtenberg machine essentially. From what I understood, that typically uses high voltages to allow the the current travelling through the wood to burn through it.

Comment: For Lichtenberg figures, you typically need a much higher DC voltage, and don't need all that lethal current that MOTs can supply. Typical wood is also likely to be too conductive to get proper figures, you would need to dry it thoroughly and select appropriate species. Make a low stage count Cockcroft Walton mutiplier driven from an ignition coil - it stands a better chance of generating the figures you're after, and is much much safer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two white wires are the 3 to 4 V 10 A heater winding, so 1/3rd of that sounds spot-on. The 2 kV output is the red wire with respect to the case, which should be grounded.

The few volts you're measuring on the red wire are due to capacitive coupling between the windings.

**Please stop before you kill yourself.**

You appear to be using standard 200 V resistors as your potential divider. Use a string of at least 20 of those in series (2 kV AC RMS is about 3 kV peak) as the hot end of your potential divider. Use a small resistor to ground to give you at least 100:1 voltage division ratio, and measure that, with respect to ground. Better still, use a proper high voltage resistor or probe. Better still, please stop before you kill yourself.

Please note that a microwave oven transformer output voltage is enough to jump through dry clothing (which mains can't do, which is why mains is *relatively* safe), and is high enough current to stop your heart in a moment (which a neon sign transformer, burner igniter or car ignition coil is unlikely to do, play with one of these if you want high voltage). Seeing that to operate your mains switch, you have to pass your hand under a loop of wire which for all you know has 2 kV on it gives me the shudders.

Comment: You can't see this in the image, but I have two switches. One in the pic that is meant to enable/disable the transformer, and a foot peddle switch that is used to turn the transformer on momentarily. Why is the case of the transformer the GND reference for 2KV instead of having a second wire? Is that how it's designed for a microwave?

Comment: Er, **pedal** switch.

Comment: You can just see the tag on the cold end of the HV winding riveted to the case in your middle picture. It's like that for safety. It's so that all HV stuff is referenced to a ground. You will sometimes see references on the net to removing that connection to float the HV winding. Don't do that. The fact that you have used ordinary resistors, and hung your meter across the middle of the divider rather than the groundy end shows me that you don't have the experience to handle the needed safety precautions. Leave one end of the HV winding solidly grounded.

Comment: This is a suicide rig if I ever saw one.

Comment: @Neil_UK Before continuing, could I ask for a recommendation on what I should understand before handling this transformer?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey What would be a better set-up? I was considering putting this in a plastic enclosure, but 6 inch by 8 inch enclosures are expensive. I shouldn't justify a less safe rig for a cheaper budget, but still.

Comment: @Jay - if you are asking these questions, you shouldn't be fooling around with thousands of volts.

Comment: @Jay I think you should understand that you're way out of your depth, and a funeral is just one trivial accident away. You can burn wood with a car ignition coil. It may take longer, but you can f%%up with an iggy coil and live to tell the tale, you don't get a second chance with a microwave oven transformer, it's just the wrong tool in the wrong hands. I can't teach you how to be safe. You either take an electricians course, or do it the amateur way and get shocked multiple times to learn what you have to learn, but from safe sources like iggy coils, not from 300lb gorillas like MOTs.

Comment: @Jay There are some high voltage forums on the net, 4HV for instance, that might be better for getting into conversation with a lot of people that do this sort of thing safely, This site has a Q/A ethos which does not really lend itself to the conversations you probably need.

Comment: @Jay Also consider having an [AED](https://www.usa.philips.com/healthcare/product/HCM5066A/heartstart-onsite-automated-external-defibrillator) on-site. Just in case. To help understand exactly why this may be useful, there's a very good book on the topic of how the heart beats called *"Sync: How Order Emerges from Chaos in the Universe, Nature, and Daily Life"* by Steven Strogatz. I have an AED here and all adults in my home are required to maintain training on it once every two years through the American Heart Association or the Red Cross (depending.)

Comment: @Jay Is your multimeter even rated to measure 2.2k V?

Comment: @Tyler No, which is why the voltage divider with the resistor was necessary.

Comment: My father was a radio ham, and when I showed an interest in the topic, and in electricity generally, he told me about a person he knew who had died. He had built a transmitter with a 200 watt power amplifier stage where the output tube had an anode voltage of 1200 DC. While tuning-up he came into contact with the tiny zero-adjustment screw on the milliameter measuring the PA plate current (around 200 mA). The post mortem found the mark on the back of his hand where he must have lightly brushed the screw head. An MOT supplies 2 kV RMS approx, or 2.8 kV peak, and much higher wattage.

Comment: @Jay - good advice is always have someone with you, who knows resuscitation methods such as CPR, and a compliant rubber mat might be sensible, too. Best advice is don't do this unless you can develop a robustly safe method of work, which your pictures show you haven't. You don't have the HV experience to do this.

Comment: The dead ham's milliameter should have been behind something like glass or Perspex/plexiglass. He was very experienced, had survived several tours of duty in the air force bombing Germany, only to die at home.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a auto transformer in primary to reduce the voltage by half or one fourth to begin with. That should do the trick.always have some one around you with instructions in case you have an accident..

Comment: [Rich S suggested](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/610196/not-getting-2-2-kv-output-on-a-microwave-transformer#comment1607568_610196) using one tenth: easier to follow, less dangerous.

Comment: Yes, a small 12 VAC transformer on the primary should get about 220 VAC on the HV secondary if the transformer is rated 2200V. Another safer test method would be applying your 120 VAC to the HV secondary, and reading much lower voltage on the primary. Then you know the winding ratio. A GFCI mains device *may* provide another layer of protection.